# Get all sets of list in prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I generate all the possible sets of the elements of a list with current length?

```
?- get_set(X, [1,2,3]).  
X = [1,1,1] ;  
X = [1,1,2] ;  
X = [1,1,3] ;  
X = [1,2,1] ;  
X = [1,2,2] ;  
X = [1,2,3] ;  
X = [1,3,1] ;  
X = [1,3,2] ;  
X = [1,3,3] ;  
.....  
X = [3,3,2] ;  
X = [3,3,3].
```

UPD: there is good answer given by Sharky.
But maybe it's not the best. Here is another:

```
get_set(X,L) :- get_set(X,L,L).

get_set([],[],_).
get_set([X|Xs],[_|T],L) :- member(X,L), get_set(Xs,T,L).
```

Comment: do you need to generate all of them at once or just define the relationship and allow a search to turn up all results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
get_set(L0, L) :-
    length(L, Len),
    length(L0, Len),
    apply_elem(L0, L).

apply_elem([], _).
apply_elem([X|Xs], L) :-
    member(X, L),
    apply_elem(Xs, L).
```

**Explanation:**

Determining the length of the input list `L` as `Len` allows us to generate a list of unique variables, `L0`, via `length/2`. Then, we simply apply elements of `L` to all members of `L0` via `member/2`, which leaves choicepoints for options, should they exist (i.e., if the list `L` is of length > 1). Prolog will backtrack to generate all possible combinations of elements of `L` into the list `L0`, as required.

Answer (score 2):

Based on library predicate [`same_length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=same_length/2), we can make it work safely in "both" directions!

Simply define `get_set/2` like this, using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915):

```
get_set(Xs,Ys) :-
   same_length(Xs,Ys),
   maplist(list_member(Ys),Xs).

list_member(Xs,X) :- 
   member(X,Xs).
```

First, the sample query suggested by the OP:

```
?- get_set(Xs,[1,2,3]).
Xs = [1,1,1] ;
Xs = [1,1,2] ;
Xs = [1,1,3] ;
Xs = [1,2,1] ;
Xs = [1,2,2] ;
Xs = [1,2,3] ;
Xs = [1,3,1] ;
Xs = [1,3,2] ;
Xs = [1,3,3] ;
Xs = [2,1,1] ;
Xs = [2,1,2] ;
Xs = [2,1,3] ;
Xs = [2,2,1] ;
Xs = [2,2,2] ;
Xs = [2,2,3] ;
Xs = [2,3,1] ;
Xs = [2,3,2] ;
Xs = [2,3,3] ;
Xs = [3,1,1] ;
Xs = [3,1,2] ;
Xs = [3,1,3] ;
Xs = [3,2,1] ;
Xs = [3,2,2] ;
Xs = [3,2,3] ;
Xs = [3,3,1] ;
Xs = [3,3,2] ;
Xs = [3,3,3] ;
false.                      % terminates universally
```

Let's try the other way round!

```
?- get_set([1,2,3],Ys).
Ys = [1,2,3] ;
Ys = [1,3,2] ;
Ys = [2,1,3] ;
Ys = [3,1,2] ;
Ys = [2,3,1] ;
Ys = [3,2,1] ;
false.                      % terminates universally
```