# generating a set of list of booleans in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to generate a list of booleans in prolog.

```
?- gener_booleans(Xs,3).
Xs = [true, true, true] ;
Xs = [true, true, false] ;
...
Xs = [false, false, false] ;
```

Here is link to another solution, but i do not know how to apply it to booleans.
[Get all sets of list in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653784/get-all-sets-of-list-in-prolog)
Can anybody help?
P.S the amount of lists is 2^N.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gener_booleans([],0).
gener_booleans([true|Xs],N) :- N>0, N1 is N-1, gener_booleans(Xs,N1).
gener_booleans([false|Xs],N) :- N>0, N1 is N-1, gener_booleans(Xs,N1).
```

Answer (score 3):

If your Prolog has the `maplist` predicate (like SWI and YAP):

```
booleans(Xs, N) :-
    length(Xs, N),
    maplist(boolean, Xs).
boolean(true).
boolean(false).
```

(I renamed the predicate `booleans` because it can also check for booleans; prefer declarative names when programming in Prolog.)

Comment: Also GNU-Prolog has `maplist/2..`. But only YAP has [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) preinstalled! Permitting: `maplist(\X^(X=true;X=false), Xs)`.  BTW: not sure: shall the type be it be `bool` or `boolean`?